# Terminal not asking for password while using sudo

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, user-accounts, sudo

Yesterday I was trying to install larbs installation on a different user. It did not work and I had to delete the other user.

When I came back to my admin user I realised that it was not asking for my password anymore even though I was using sudo commands in my terminal.
Also while I was trying to make a new user, it didn't work as when I was trying to log into it and it comes back to my admin user page.

Please do reply as this causing me a lot of trouble as a college student as I have to separate my personal user from my college one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What's your Linux distro (`cat /etc/os-release` and `uname -a`)? Exactly what commands did you use creating and deleting your new user? What other actions you took in that context? Can you please post output of `cat /etc/sudoers`? Do you have anything in `/etc/sudoers.d/`? If yes, please include the content of those files as well. Please don't answer in comments, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1773665/edit) the question instead so relevant info is available. Enclose commands and text output in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Please [edit] and clarify: (1) What exactly did you do? With what exact commands/tools/windows/methods? (2) "it was not asking for my password anymore even though i was using sudo commands in my terminal" – Did the commands work? (3) "while im trying to make a new user, it does not work as when i try logging into it, it comes back to my admin user page" – What is the "admin user page"? My first connotation is with web pages you see in a browser. Do you log in via a browser? If so then maybe you do other things in a browser and this is something that contributes to the problem somehow.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `sudo` will stop asking for passwords for a period of time. This is a 'user friendliness' feature. You can set this in `/etc/sudoers`. You have to edit that file with `visudo`.

Set this period with

```
USER timestamp_timeout=5
```

to set this period to 5 minutes, or

```
USER timestamp_timeout=0
```

to force asking for password every time.

Make also sure, that there is no rule with `NOPASSWD` applicable for you in this file.

Comment: should i add the above to the sudoers file. i tried but nothing changed.